# Replace apostrophe with whitespace in java

Tags: java, string

I want to replace all the apostrophes inside a string with a whitespace. But i tried this and it doesn't work. How can i solve this?

```
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'", " ");
```

Comment: the input string was from a verse of an italian poet "Così tra questa Immensità s’annega il pensier mio"

Comment: `’` is not `'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the input string you shared in the comments ("Così tra questa Immensità s’annega il pensier mio"), the character there isn't a regular single quote ('), but an apostrophe (’), so you should use that in your `replaceAll` call:

```java
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("’", " ");
```

You could also use a regex to replace both quotes and apostrophes, of course:

```java
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("[’']", " ");
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, didn't notice the difference between those two!

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to **escape character**

use this insted

```
inputString = inputString..replaceAll("\'","")
```

for all list you can visit [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: There is no need to escape an apostrophe in a string literal or in a regular expression.  It is not special.  You would need to escape it in a character literal.